# Android - Run async methods in order (sequentially)

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, retrofit

I'm using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library on my Android app to make HTTP calls to an API.
I'm using the `Callback` way to access the results, ie running it on async mode.

Now, some `Retrofit` calls will depend on the result of previous `Retrofit` calls, in other words, I can only call `methodB()` when I've received the result from `methodA()`.

I thought about implementing an `IntentService` and call the Retrofit methods there but I don't find it very elegant to accomplish what I want.

Is there any elegant and better way to make this async calls run synchronized?

Comment: intentservice with retrofit in sync mode is fine, you can also use an asynctask if your calls are related to a single activity. otherwise, you'd have to call the next method from the callback of the previous one (which can be hard to read after a few levels), or you can use a single thread executor (see http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.Builder.html#setExecutors-java.util.concurrent.Executor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) but that does not seem entirely appropriate in your case

Comment: Moving to an `IntentService` will force me to change some parts of my code design so I'm trying to use the `IntentService` way as a last resort option. I'm all set with asynchronous Retrofit but due to a change on the API I'm calling I need to make some methods only run after getting the result from another method. So I'm trying to fix this with the less possible changes to my code design. Nevertheless thanks for your comment.

Comment: you could take a look at RxJava, it uses Observables to allow chaining of values, see the presentation from Jake Wharton: https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/2014-1

Comment: @dwnz Have you sorted this issue, if so please answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: @StevieG just added my answer, I completely forgot I had this question still open.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using Retrofit in sync mode and execute the sync calls on an `IntentService`.

The other solution, as pointed out by njzk2 in the comments, could be calling async tasks on the `callback` but that would lead to nested code which could make the code barely readable.

I'm still interested in a better approach than the `IntentService` with `Retrofit` in sync mode, if you have one feel free to share.